# Average "score" of each row of pd.Serie based on its content mapped via another score Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a (very large) Series that contains keywords (each row contain multiple keywords separated by a '-', for example

```
In[5]: word_series
Out[5]: 
0    the-cat-is-pink
1           blue-sea
2      best-job-ever
dtype: object
```

I have another Series that contains a score attributes to each word (the words are the index, the scores are the values), for example:

```
In[7]: all_scores
Out[7]: 
the     0.34
cat     0.56
best    0.01
ever    0.77
is      0.12
pink    0.34
job     0.01
sea     0.87
blue    0.65
dtype: float64
```

All the words in my word_series appear in my scores. I am trying to find the fastest way to attribute a score to each row of word_series, based on the average score of each of its words from all_scores. If a row is n/a the score should be the average of scores.

I have tried using apply this way, but it is was too slow.

```
scores = word_series.apply(
        lambda x: all_scores[x.split('-')].mean()).fillna(
        all_scores.mean())
```

I then thought I could split all_words into columns using str.replace and maybe perform a matrix multiplication type operation using this new matrix M and my words like M.mul(all_scores) where each row in M be matched to values based on the the index of all_scores. That would be a first step, to get the mean I could then jut divide by the number of non-na on each row

```
In[9]: all_words.str.split('-', expand=True)
Out[9]: 
      0    1     2     3
0   the  cat    is  pink
1  blue  sea  None  None
2  best  job  ever  None
```

Is such an operation possible? Or is there another fast way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Working with strings data is slow in pandas, so use list comprehension with map by `Series` and `mean`:

```
from statistics import mean

L = [mean(all_scores.get(y) for y in x.split('-')) for x in word_series]
a = pd.Series(L, index=word_series.index)
print (a)

0    0.340000
1    0.760000
2    0.263333
dtype: float64
```

Or:

```
def mean(a):
    return sum(a) / len(a)

L = [mean([all_scores.get(y) for y in x.split('-')]) for x in word_series]
a = pd.Series(L, index=word_series.index)
```

If possible some values not matched add parameter `np.nan` to `get` and use [`numpy.nanmean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html):

```
L = [np.nanmean([all_scores.get(y, np.nan) for y in x.split('-')]) for x in word_series]
a = pd.Series(L, index=word_series.index)
```

Or:

```
def mean(a):
    return sum(a) / len(a)

L = [mean([all_scores.get(y, np.nan) for y in x.split('-') if y in all_scores.index]) 
      for x in word_series]
```

Answer (score 0):

heres a way

**print(a)**

```
             words
0  the-cat-is-pink
1         blue-sea
2    best-job-ever
```

**print(b)**

```
      all_scores
the         0.34
cat         0.56
best        0.01
ever        0.77
is          0.12
pink        0.34
job         0.01
sea         0.87
blue        0.65

b = b.reset_index()
```

**print(b)**

```
  index  all_scores
0   the        0.34
1   cat        0.56
2  best        0.01
3  ever        0.77
4    is        0.12
5  pink        0.34
6   job        0.01
7   sea        0.87
8  blue        0.65

a['score'] = a['words'].str.split('-').apply(lambda x: sum([b[b['index'] == w].reset_index()['all_scores'][0] for w in x])/len(x))
```

**output**

```
             words     score
0  the-cat-is-pink  0.340000
1         blue-sea  0.760000
2    best-job-ever  0.263333
```

Comment: @tishu wants `mean` not the `sum`